# Why does attr() not update the HTML when called a second time?

Tags: jquery, dom-traversal

I have a script that is supposed to select all descendant input checkbox, when the ancestor checkbox is selected.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/zJPfR/

When the top-level checkbox is selected, all checkboxes underneath are selected. If you unselect the checkbox, the checks are removed. However if you attempt to do this a second time, it doesn't work.

If I'm going about this incorrectly, please let me know.

Darius

```
        $('.poSelect').click(function() {
        var expandBox   = $(this).parents('.pohelpTbl').next('.expandBox');
        var receipts    = expandBox.find('input[type="checkbox"]');

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            var status = true;
        } else {
            var status = false;
        }

        $(receipts).each(function (i) {
            var cb = $(this);
            cb.attr("checked",status);          
        });
    });
```

Comment: You don't need the `if`/`else` or the `each()`; just use: [`receipts.prop('checked', this.checked);`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zJPfR/5/)

Comment: Understood! I wonder why I was down-voted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
$('.poSelect').click(function() {
    var receipts    = $(this).closest('.pohelpTbl').next('.expandBox').find(':checkbox');

    receipts.prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

There is no need to iterate through each of the `receipts` items, you can call `.prop()` directly on `receipts`.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zJPfR/8/)

Comment: Why are you using jQuery to test the `checked` property? Just use `this.checked`. It returns a Boolean all by itself.

Comment: That's very interesting, Arun. I actually like this method a lot better, assuming that nothing else needed to be done within that loop.

Comment: Most of the times there are no need to iterate through the jquery element collection, jquery will take care of propagating the operation to all the elements in the operated collection.

Answer (score 5):

jQuery's `.attr` only uses the initial attributes. Use [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) instead of `.attr` to change the current DOM. 

`cb.attr("checked",status);` => `cb.prop("checked",status);`

Answer (score 0):

The checked attribute's presence is what shows the checkbox to be checked, not if the value of the attribute is being set to true or false.

change from this:

```
var cb = $(this);
cb.attr("checked",status);
```

to this:

```
var cb = $(this);
if (status){
    cb.attr("checked","checked");
}
else{
    cb.removeAttr("checked");
}
```